# Some keys of my macbook is not working

Tags: keyboard, macbook, boot-camp

When I use my Macbook on Mac side, the letter <kbd>D</kbd> on the keybord is not working, but when I shift to Windows the letter <kbd>D</kbd> works just fine.

What could be the problem and what is its solution?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://ccm.net/forum/affich-80743-mac-keyboard-key-b-does-not-work), you should check your Speech settings.

Under `System Preferences>System>Speech> Text to Speech` make sure that *Speak selected text when the key is pressed* is unchecked.

[image]

Comment: it works just fine after unchecking that thing........thanks